# Problem with react-hook-form - api gets null values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm doing application with friends. I'm using react-hook-form. The api gets only null values. It's a very crucial element of our application. Please help, here is my code:

```
  const NewItemBar = ({ isVisible, handleClose }) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = ({ name, data, description }) => {
    api
      .post(endpoints.createTask, {
        name,
        data,
        description,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
  return (
    <StyledWrapper handleClose={handleClose} isVisible={isVisible}>
      <StyledHeading big>Dodaj zadanie do wykonania</StyledHeading>
      <StyledForm onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <StyledInput
          placeholder="nazwa zadania"
          type="text"
          name="name"
          {...register('name', { required: 'Required' })}
        />
        <StyledInput
          placeholder="data wykonania"
          type="text"
          name="data"
          {...register('data', { required: 'Required' })}
        />
        <StyledTextArea
          type="text"
          placeholder="opis"
          name="description"
          as="textarea"
          {...register('description', { required: 'Required' })}
        />
        <StyledButton type="submit">Zapisz</StyledButton>
      </StyledForm>
    </StyledWrapper>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please clarify "The api gets only null values". Do you mean name, data, and description are passed to the API request with null values on submit? Please edit your question accordingly so you can get appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

In case of custom components you should create wrapper using `Controller` or pass a function with `forwardRef`.

https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingwithUIlibraries

forwardRef might be useful when you want your component to manage inner state on it's own.
For example:

```
const PhoneInput = forwardRef(
    (
        {
            id,
            name,
            label,
            placeholder,
            errorMsg,
            onSubmit,
            onChange,
            onBlur,
            disabled,
        },
        ref
    ) => {
        const [value, setValue] = useState("");

        const _onChange = (value) => {
            setValue(value);
            onChange(value);
        };

        const classes = (className) =>
            [
                className,
                disabled ? "disabled" : "",
                errorMsg ? "is-invalid" : "",
            ].join(" ");

        console.log(value);

        return (
            <div className={classes("f-form-group phone-input")}>
                <div className="phone-input-wrap">
                    <div className="inputs">
                        <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
                        <NumberFormat
                            className={classes("f-form-control")}
                            name={name}
                            id={id}
                            type="tel"
                            format="+7 (###) ### ##-##"
                            mask="_"
                            placeholder={placeholder}
                            value={value}
                            onChange={(e) => _onChange(e.target.value)}
                            onBlur={onBlur}
                            getInputRef={ref}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className="btn btn-primary"
                        onClick={() => onSubmit(value)}
                    >
                        Подтвердить
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="invalid-feedback">{errorMsg}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
);
```